# JavaScript - Is it possible to decrement counter within for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, counter, decrement

I'm trying to iterate over an array and in certain situations need to decrement my counter.

My goal is to rearrange divs into two columns with a fixed height.

It looks like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(left column is not full) {
        left.append(divs[i]);
    }
    else if(right column is not full){
        right.append(divs[i]);
    }
    else {
        create 2 new columns (left & right);
        i--; //so that the element doesn't get lost
    }
}
```

I don't end up in an infinite loop, but the result isn't quite what i expected. Is there an error in my logic or is it simply impossible/not allowed to decrement the counter from within the loop?

Comment: Manipulating the loop variable inside the loop should be possible. What behavior exactly do you expect and what behavior exactly do you see instead?

Comment: It is valid code, but most of the time this does not makes sense or makes the code hard to read.

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. I'm having a hard time thinking of a usecase  for this...

Comment: Instead of trying to guess where the problem in your code might be, you would solve your issue much quicker if you posted your **actual** code and asked about the **actual** problem.

Comment: i editet my question and hope it's a little clearer now

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad practice to modify a counter within a loop.

Use `while` instead. Then you will be able to define your custom counter modifying logics.

For example, the snippet below removes all negative items from an array using the following algorithm:

- if an item is positive - continue
- otherwise, remove an item in position `i`

It isn't possible to do this with a `for` loop without either additional array or manual counter decrement, as `for` loop would skip the value after a removed one every time.

```js
var items = [0, 3, 5, -3, -5, -7, 11];

var i = 0; 

while (i < items.length) {
  if (items[i] < 0) 
    items.splice(i, 1);
  else
    i++;
}

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(items);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can decrement counters in `for` loops but you will find it hard to keep track on them. for your case it's simply better to use a `while` loop.

how about this:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < length) {
    if(a) {
        //do something
        i++;
    }
    else {
        //do something else
        i--;
    }
}
```